# Py 3.6 // Django 2.1.4 : Accessing User Profile mysteriously changes the status of user.is_authenticated to True

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views

I have been having this problem for 2 weeks now I can't seem to solve it.

I have a social website where user's can upload their resumes for recruiters to see.

And when I access some user's profile, the Navbar acts as if I am logged in, which I am not.

I tried fixing this issue by using `get_queryset()` ,it worked but I couldn't manage to display user's profile data.

so I stuck with `get()`.

Here's a visual explanation:

As you can see the navbar says **Home/Login/Signin**

[image: Picture 1]

Now if I access John Doe's Profile, the navbar will switch to **Home/Profile/Logout**:

[image: Picture 2]

Here's my code;

**views.py**:

```
class HomeProfile(ListView):
"Di splays all active users in db"

    template_name = 'profile/home_profile.html'
    queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(is_active=True)


class Get_Profile(DetailView):
"fetches user's profile"

    def get(self, request, pk):
        user = MyModel.objects.get(pk=pk)
        return render(request, 'profile/profile.html', {'user':user})
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [

    path('homepage/profiles/', user_view.HomeProfile.as_view(), name='homepage'),
    path('homepage/profile/<int:pk>/', user_view.Get_Profile.as_view(), name='user-profile'),

]
```

**base_test.html**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark sticky-top">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'home' %}">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler d-lg-none" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavId" aria-controls="collapsibleNavId"
            aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavId">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'homepage' %}">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                {% if not user.is_authenticated %}
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'login' %}">Log In</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'signup' %}">Sign Up</a>
                    </li>
                {% else %}
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Profile</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Log Out</a>
                    </li>
                {% endif %}
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

**home_profile.html**

```
<!-- this is the home template that displays all active users -->

{% extends 'base_test.html' %}

{% block title %} My Site | Profiles {% endblock title %}

{% block content  %}

   <div class="card-columns text-center padding">
   {% for user in mymodel_list %}
       <div class="card">
           <img class="rounded-circle" src="{{user.profile.image.url}}" width=150 height=150>
           <div class="card-body">
               <h5 class="card-title">Full name : {{user.get_full_name}}</h5>
               <p class="crad-text">Occupation/job : {{user.profile.occupation}}</p>
               <a type="button" href="{% url 'user-profile' user.pk %}" style="color:whitesmoke;" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Profile</a>
           </div>
       </div>
    {% endfor %}
   </div>
{% endblock content  %}

{% block footer %}

{% endblock footer %}
```

**profile.html**

```
<!-- user profile template -->
{% extends 'base_test.html' %}
{% load custom_tags %}

{% block title %} My Site | {{user.get_full_name}} {% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 order-lg-2 padding">
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane active" id="profile">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <h6><strong>About</strong></h6>
                            <p>
                                {{user.profile.bio}}
                            </p>
                            <hr>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <h6><strong>Skills</strong></h6>
                            {% for skill in user.profile.skills|split:',' %}
                                <span class="badge badge-primary">{{skill}}</span>
                            {% endfor %}
                            <hr>
                            <h6><strong>Hobbies</strong></h6>
                            <p>
                                {% for hobbie in user.profile.hobbies|split:',' %}
                                    <span class="badge badge-success">{{hobbie}}</span>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </p>
                            <hr>
                        </div>
                       <!-- removes the social part -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 order-lg-1 padding">
            <h1 class="mb-3 text-center">{{user.get_full_name}}</h1>
            <hr>
            <img src="{{user.profile.image.url}}" class="mx-auto img-fluid rounded-circle d-block" alt="avatar" width=150><br>

            <div class="text-center">
                <h4>{{user.profile.school}}</h4>
                <p><strong>Hometown :</strong> {{ user.profile.hometown}}</p>
                <p><strong>Current City:</strong> {{user.profile.location}}<p>
                <p><strong>Occupation/Job:</strong> {{user.profile.occupation}}<p><br>
                <hr>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-md">View CV</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}

{% block footer %}

{% endblock footer %}
```

**I don't know What is causing this strange behaviour!!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you are mixing up with `request.user` and your user object for resume. You should change the context variable name from `user` to something else. for example:

```
class Get_Profile(DetailView):
"fetches user's profile"

    def get(self, request, pk):
        user = MyModel.objects.get(pk=pk)
        return render(request, 'profile/profile.html', {'profile':user})  # <-- Here
```

Answer (score 0):

You've used the same variable name, `user`, for the user whose profile you are viewing as for the one who is actually using the site. You need to pick another name.

(Also, unrelated, but you don't need to - and shouldn't - define the `get` method in your detail view.)

Comment: i know i tried using get_queryset(), but i didnt manage to display the user's profile data.

Comment: i mentioned that before